# WebView app opens YouTube app?

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I have a Android WebView app and it has YouTube videos embedded in it. I have looked all over for the answer but could not find it. Is there a way to make the YouTube app open when they look at the videos on my site? Yes I know some people don't have the YouTube app, but this is an app for a local go kart track in a small town, so I can give instructions whenever someone has a problem. :)

Comment: The intent should automatically trigger a prompt for the user, asking which app to start it with (youtube or web browser). Is this not the case here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simply because you've set this as a user .

go to Settings and Applications , then , in the settings of the browser click the clear-Defaults button and it should now ask you how to open the video link.

however , if you wish to make the app to not listen to the user's settings , you can do so as well, by using "[setComponent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent%28android.content.ComponentName%29)".

you could also know how to open the main activity of the app by using:

```
getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(...);
```